# Conflicting cross-version suffixes akka-actor, akka-slf4j

Tags: playframework, sbt, apache-kafka, typesafe-activator

I am trying to add Kafka to a Play application (using Typesafe Activator version 1.3.2).

Below I have listed my `build.sbt` file. I copied how to obtain the Kafka dependencies for a Play application from [Kafka's FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetKafkadependenciestoworkinPlayframework?)

**build.sbt**

```
name := """Test"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

resolvers += "Apache repo" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.2",
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.3.1",
   "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
   "org.mashupbots.socko" % "socko-webserver_2.9.2" % "0.2.2",
   "nl.grons" % "metrics-scala_2.9.2" % "3.0.0",
   "com.codahale.metrics" % "metrics-core" % "3.0.0",
   "io.backchat.jerkson" % "jerkson_2.9.2" % "0.7.0",
   "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.3.8",
   "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2",
   "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.9.2" % "0.8.2.1" excludeAll (
     ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j")
  )
)
```

On compiling I am getting following error:

```
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor _2.11, <none>
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j _2.11, <none>
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor, com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that wiki is quite out of date, and in particular doesn't use sbt's `%%` notation for scala-based dependencies.

As you have a Scala 2.11.1 project, I switched to using `%%` instead of the explicit scala version, and also updated all the dependencies (some old versions don't have releases for Scala 2.11).

Try using these dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "joda-time"                % "joda-time"       % "2.7",
  "org.joda"                 % "joda-convert"    % "1.7",
  "ch.qos.logback"           % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3",
  "org.mashupbots.socko"    %% "socko-webserver" % "0.6.0",
  "nl.grons"                %% "metrics-scala"   % "3.4.0_a2.3",
  "io.dropwizard.metrics"    % "metrics-core"    % "3.1.1",
  "com.gilt"                %% "jerkson"         % "0.6.7",
  "com.amazonaws"            % "aws-java-sdk"    % "1.9.30",
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core"   % "0.11.2",
  "org.apache.kafka"        %% "kafka"           % "0.8.2.1" excludeAll (
     ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j")
  )
)
```

Comment: I am unable to use latest socko-webserver 0.6.0 with scala version 2.10.5
As per http://sockoweb.org/download.html I am using "org.mashupbots.socko" % "socko-webserver_2.11" % "0.6.0"